# '*' and '/' not recognized on input by a read statement

Tags: fortran

I start learning Fortran and I'm doing a little case test program where the user types two real numbers and selects an arithmetic operators (from + - * /).  The following error appears when the user selects "*"

```
F6502 : read <con> - positive integer expected in repeat field
```

and if the user selects "/" the compiler executes the default case, and displays this message

```
invalid operator, thanks
the result is 0.000000E+00
```

The program is as follows.

```
program operateur
implicit none

   CHARACTER(LEN=1) :: oper 
   real::a,b,res
   print*,'Give the first number a :'
   read*,a
   print*,'Give the second number b :'
   read*,b
   print*,'which operation ?'
   read*,oper
   !print*,'donnez a,b,oper :'
  ! read(*,*)a,b,oper

               select case (oper)

                  case ('+')      
                  res=a+b

                  case ('-')       
                  res=a-b

                  case ('*')       
                  res=a*b


                  case ('/')       
                  res=a/b           

                  case default
                  print*, "Invalid Operator, thanks" 

               end select

   print*,'the result is ',res 

end program operateur
```

Comment: This is likely down to your use of _list-directed_ input.  Here, `*` and `/` mean special things in terms of input.  You could read up on using an explicit format.  I'm afraid I haven't time to search for a good question here.

Comment: # Dmitri Chubarov what can i do to resolve these errors with * and /

Comment: The compiler didn't recognize : and x       --> compilation error

Comment: But why the compiler didn't recognize * and / as characters and executes the program normaly for + and - and they are also characters

Comment: Ok, thanks after using read (*,"(A1)") oper the program is working. can you please explain me the cause of * and / case errors

Answer (score 8):

FORTRAN input and output formatting rules are rather involved. Each input and ouptut statement has two arguments that have special meaning. For example

```
  READ (10,"(2I10)") m,n
```

The first argument is a *file descriptor*. Here it is `10`. The second argument `"(2I10)"` is the *format specifier*. If you give an asterisk (`*`) as a format specifier you switch on the list-directed formatting mode.

List directed input as the name suggests is controlled by the argument list of the input operator.

#### 1. Why asterisk (`*`) is special in list-directed input mode?

The input list is split into one or more input records. Each input record is of the form `c`, `k*c` or `k*` where `c` is a literal constant, and `k` is an integer literal constant. For example,

```
  5*1.01
```

as an instance of `k*c` scheme is interpreted as 5 copies of number `1.01`

```
   5*
```

is interpreted as 5 copies of null input record.

The symbol asterisk (`*`) has a special meaning in list-directed input mode. Some compiler runtimes would report a runtime error when they encounter asterisk without an integer constant in list-directed input, other compilers would read an asterisk. For instance GNU Fortran compiler is known for standards compliance, so its runtime would accept `*`. Other compiler runtimes might fail.

#### 2. What's up with slash (`/`)?

A comma (`,`), a slash (`/`) and a sequence of one or more blanks ( ) are considered *record separators* in list-directed input mode.

There is no simple way to input a slash on its own in this mode.

#### 3. Possible solution: specify format explicitly

What you can do to make the runtime accept a single slash or an asterisk is to leave the list-directed input mode by specifying the format explicitly:

```
read (*,"(A1)") oper
```

should let you input any single character.

Comment: @imadeddine You don't have to thank in the comments, you don't have to enter the fixed code as an answer but you should probably accept the answer if it fixed your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Ok then the correct source code is

```
program operateur
implicit none

CHARACTER(LEN=1) :: oper 
real::a,b,res
print*,'Give the first number a :'
read*,a
print*,'Give the second number b :'
read*,b
print*,'which operation ?'
read (*,"(A1)") oper


           select case (oper)

              case ('+')      
              res=a+b

              case ('-')       
              res=a-b

              case ('*')       
              res=a*b


              case ('/')       
              res=a/b           

              case default
              print*, "Invalid Operator, thanks" 

           end select

   print*,'the result is ',res 

end program operateur
```

Comment: I suggest you to learn how to format the code properly. You actually don't have to put another answer here, you can just accept the explanation which have helped you. Do NOT use anything like !!!!!! or other chat features.