# Read CHARACTER string without knowing the length

Tags: string, fortran, fortran77

I have to read input data in my Fortran 77 program. It Looks as following

```
FILENAME PATH

temperature  ./Data
```

and then in the Fortran code I proceed as following

```
CHARACTER*8 FILENAME,PATH

READ(5,'(A80)') CARDIN 

READ(5,*) FILENAME,PATH
```

but the problem is that I don't know the length of `FILENAME` and `PATH` in advance. So what if the user doesn't give names that are not exactly 8? Do you have any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Do you truly have a requirement to use/be restricted by Fortran 77?

Comment: Be aware of problems [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36863608) when reading file paths (containing unquoted slashes) with list-directed input.

Comment: I suggest you read the ISO standard documentation for FORTRAN 77 on Hollerith constants or how assumed-size arrays apply to `character` types. I don't know of any way to achieve your goal without resorting to features from newer Fortran standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can do it in F77, but this is more F90 in style.

```
INTEGER*4 FUNCTION LengthString(String)
IMPLICIT NONE
CHARACTER* String
INTEGER*4 I

LengthString = -1 !default is -1 just because.

DO I=LEN(String), 1, -1
  IF(String(I:I) .ne. ' ') THEN
     LengthString = I
     EXIT
  ENDIF
ENDDO

RETURN
END FUNCTION LengthString
```

And the program could be something like this:

```
PROGRAM Main
CHARACTER*80 AA
INTEGER*4 LenAA
...
LenAA = LengthString(AA)
IF(LenAA .lt. 1) !error out
...
WRITE(*,10) LenAA, A(1:LenAA)
10 FORMAT('AA(',I4,')="',A,'"')
...
```

Open statement could look like this:

```
OPEN(FILE=AA(1:LenAA),...
```

And the path is the same deal.

```
NewLongFile = Path(1:LenPath) // '/' // AA(1:LenAA)
Len_NewLongFile = LengthString(NewLongFile)
```

Comment: What is objectionable about `len_trim`?

Comment: i see what you mean @francescalus ! I had rolled my own a long time ago... [strokes beard -n- chins]

Comment: To be fair, `len_trim` isn't F77 (but then, neither is `enddo`).

Comment: Your code does the job but does not answer the original question. @MorganeMaPh explicitly said that he/she must restrict themselves to FORTRAN 77. `implicit none`, `len_trim` for character manipulation, `end do` loop termination, and the `exit` statement were introduced in Fortran 90/95. Never mind the 6 character length restriction for naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but you can use `TRIM` to "cut" the blanc space:

```
      Program TEST
      CHARACTER*50 FILENAME,PATH

      READ(*,*) FILENAME,PATH
      WRITE(*,*)TRIM(FILENAME),TRIM(PATH)
      END
```

Comment: Nice use of TRIM. I usually use 80, 128, 256, or 1024. And then a seperate variable to understand the length. You will quickly find a function to find the end of the string can be useful even if you also use TRIM. And useful for a variety of flexible output handling of strings.

Comment: Thank you @PeMa could work... What I would like to do is write a Statement like "Read the string until you get a blanc space".

Comment: The problem is not in writing, but in reading. This is not a good solution.

Comment: Exactly @VladimirF ... also as I defined the variable I already have to give a length... this is bad

Comment: TRIM is not Fortran 77.