# Does this code demonstrate a bug in GFortran?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

As you can see from the code below, when it asks you whether to carry on or stop the program, by pressing other keys like ";" or "," it reads it as if you had pressed the "Y" or "y" key but you didn't. So, I'm asking whether this is a bug in the compiler, or a problem with the code?

```
program vols

!Calculates difference in volume of 2 spheres
implicit none

real :: rad1,rad2,vol1,vol2
character :: response

do
print *, 'Please enter the two radii'
read *, rad1,rad2
call volume(rad1,vol1)
call volume(rad2,vol2)
write(*,10) 'The difference in volumes is, ',abs(vol1-vol2)
10       format(a,2f10.3)
print *, 'Any more? - hit Y for yes, otherwise hit any key'
read *, response
if (response /= 'Y' .and. response /= 'y') stop
end do

end program vols

!________________________________________________

subroutine volume(rad,vol)
implicit none
real :: rad,vol,pi
!calculates the volume of a sphere
pi=4.0*atan(1.0)
vol=4./3.*pi*rad*rad*rad
!It's a little quicker in processing to  do r*r*r than r**3!
end subroutine volume
```

Comment: Welcome, please use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions.

Comment: Consider what `response /= 'Y'` evaluates to if `response` is `;` (or almost anything else, try `n`).  Now consider `response /= 'y'` and think about `.and.`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark So, why when we omit `.and. response /='y'` it works fine?

Comment: If you input 'Y' or 'y' in the first run, the value of variable "response" is 'Y' or 'y', and then if you input ',' in the second run, the input to response is NULL so by the LIST-DIRECTED interpretation, the variable "response" is unchanged, so it keeps the value 'Y'/'y'.
Intel compiler also loops for ','.

In the case of ';', I don't know, maybe gfortran's bug.

Answer (score 3):

Without more details on your exact input we cannot conclude that this is a bug in gfortran.  Instead, there is a feature of the program which may lead to "confusing" behaviour.

For getting the response, the program uses list-directed input.  This leads to non-intuitive results.  For example, for [someone writing a calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36863608/3157076) there may be surprise about what happens when someone enters `*` or `/`.

In the calculator example, `*` is involved in repeat counts and `/` in record separators.  For this question `,` also has a special meaning.  In list-directed input `,` is a value separator and `read *, x` presented with that character doesn't set `x` to the value `','`.

Instead, the input statement

```
read *, response
```

when presented with input

```
,
```

will come to the `,` and see "hah, the user is telling me that there's no value specified".  This contrasts with the empty line, where input processing continues to wait for a value.

This value separator couples with another feature of list-directed input: null values are allowed.  A null value completes the input statement but leaves the corresponding value *unchanged* (not set to blank).

This means that if the input goes like

```
1 1
y
1 1
,
```

On the second pass, the character `response` is *unchanged* from the value `'y'`.  Equally, for

```
1 1
,
```

`response` is unchanged from its undefined status: the program isn't allowed to compare its value with `'y`'.

How to address this?  Simply use an appropriate format:

```
read '(A)', response
```

In this way, input `,` is treated as a character not as a value separator.

Although commas are treated in a special way in the list-directed input of the question, semicolons are not.  If you see unexpected behaviour with a semicolon input then that could be a cause for concern.  I don't see that happen with the gfortran available to me.

However, semicolons *may* be special.  When the decimal edit mode is `COMMA` (rather than the default `POINT`), then a semicolon is treated as a value separator instead of a comma (which now acts as a decimal separator in values such as `1,23`).  `COMMA` is not the default mode of a connection.

Comment: I saw that even the semicolon did the same trick, which leaves one in doubt!

Comment: Can you provide your full input and compiler version?  There could be a compiler problem, but having exactly what you enter would be needed to look further.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - I tried this code in Intel Fortran and it works as expected. When `response` is `y` or `Y` it loops otherwise it exits the loop.

```
program vols

!Calculates difference in volume of 2 spheres
implicit none

real :: rad1,rad2,vol1,vol2
character :: response

do
    print *, 'Please enter the two radii'
    read *, rad1,rad2
    call volume(rad1,vol1)
    call volume(rad2,vol2)
    print '(a,2f10.3)', 'The difference in volumes is, ',abs(vol1-vol2)
    print *, 'Any more? - hit Y for yes, otherwise hit any key'
    read *, response
    if (response /= 'Y' .and. response /= 'y') stop
end do

contains

subroutine volume(rad,vol)
implicit none
real :: rad,vol,pi
!calculates the volume of a sphere
pi=4.0*atan(1.0)
vol=4./3.*pi*rad*rad*rad
!It's a little quicker in processing to  do r*r*r than r**3!
end subroutine volume

end program vols
```

So it seems and problems might be specific to `gfortran` here.

PS. I moved the function in the `program` block such that it does not need an interface, or external declaration.

PS2. I checked the compilation result and `rad**3` is identical to `rad*rad*rad`. Modern compilers are smarted than you think. It is better to show *intent* in the programs rather than obscuring it with micro-optimizations.

Comment: can we say that's certainly a bug?

Comment: @Student404Mus - I can't because I am not a `gfortran` user. I just wanted to compare with a different compiler.