# read file character by character fortran

Tags: file, io, fortran

I'm using GNU fortran. I'd like to be able to read a file into a string, and then iterate over every character in that file OR simply read the file character by character. Here's what I tried:

```
character(len=:) , allocatable :: content
! this would normally allocate to the file size, but I'm making a minimal example
allocate(character(256) :: content) 
open(unit=2, file='test.txt', status='old')
read(2, *) content
close(2)
print *, content
```

But this only prints the first line and I'm not really sure why.

Comment: this still only reads the first line. or perhaps I'm only printing the first line?

Comment: You want to open the file with `access="stream"`.  You can then read the file 1 character at a time and stuff it into a buffer.

Comment: Or `advance = 'No'` and read it one character at a time and use end of record markers to find the line breaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you name this code 'a.f90' and compile it will print itself.

```
program foo
   character(len=:), allocatable :: str
   integer fd
   allocate(character(len=216) :: str)
   open(newunit=fd, file='a.f90', access='stream')
   read(fd) str
   close(fd)
   print *, str
end program foo
```

BTW, to make this more useful, you can use `inquire(file='a.f90', size=sz)` to determine the file size, and then do the allocation with `allocate(character(len=sz-1) :: str)`.  The minus 1 removes EOF.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to read a file into a string, you should read the file in a loop until you reach its end and concatenate each string with the previous result. Something like this:

```
character (len = 256) :: string_all_file
character (len = 40) :: current_string

rows = 0 !Count the number of lines in a file
string_all_file = '';
DO
  READ(2, *, iostat=io) current_string
  IF (io/ = 0) EXIT
  rows = rows + 1
  string_all_file = string_all_file // current_string
END DO
```

I can make mistakes in the syntax. I haven't used fortran for a long time.

Comment: *I can make mistakes in the syntax* One wee mistake is the use of `+` for concatenating strings, Fortran uses `//`.  And I'm not sure what use you propose for the `rows` counter.

Comment: And using list-directed input is [surely the wrong thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36863608/3157076) to do.

Comment: The concatenation also requires the use of `trim()`.  `string_all_file = trim((string_all_file) // trim(current_string)`; otherwise there will likely be a slew of blanks embedded in the string.

Comment: Согласен со всеми комментариями. Было дано направление поиска, а не готовое решение. Понимаю, что идеальных решений не существует!