# how to read a csv file from fortran if the data is different for each colum

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am trying to rea csv file in fortran, but failed.

I have this data in my csv file

```
0,2013/02/20,24.448
1,2013/02/20,24.448
2,2013/02/20,24.545
3,2013/02/20,24.448
4,2013/02/20,24.351
5,2013/02/20,24.351
```

And I try to define it like this

`real,allocatable :: array(:,:)` 
But, when I print, the printed data looks all wrong.
I assume it is because I define it as real but apparently it is not.

This is the read command I use

```
do
     num_rows = num_rows + 1
     read(10, *, iostat=io) data(num_rows, 1), data(num_rows, 2), data(num_rows, 3)
     if (io /= 0) exit ! Exit the loop when there is no data left to read
  end do
```

How can I solve this ?

Comment: You [cannot use list-directed input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36863608/3157076) when the input has a `/` like this. But then, a date isn't a real number either. How do you want to store the data from the input?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking tue [tour] and reading [ask]. It is good to always explicitly say what exact output you got. However here, as franvescalus pointed out, you should tell us how you want to store the date like `2013/02/20`, it is not just a real number. Do you want it stored as three independent numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read what is essentially a character (e.g. 2013/02/20) into a real variable.

Best to read CSV files into character arrays first then convert individual characters into reals by reading as "internal files"; e.g. `read( string, * ) real_value`

Once you have an array of characters you can pick off individual columns.

Provided your CSV file is comma-delimited and none of those commas are actually part of cell data then the following will read your file.

```
module MyModule
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: MAXLEN = 1000

   type Element
      character(len=:), allocatable :: value     ! single value in a cell
   end type Element

   type Line
      type(Element), allocatable :: column(:)    ! collection of cells in a row
   end type Line

   type Spreadsheet
      type(Line), allocatable :: row(:)          ! collection of rows
   end type Spreadsheet


contains
   type(Spreadsheet) function readCSVFile( filename )
      character(len=*), intent(in) :: filename
      character(len=MAXLEN) buffer
      integer i, j
      integer stat
      integer numRows, numCols
      integer start, lineLength

      ! Read file once to determine the number of rows
      open( 10, file=filename)
      numRows = 0
      do
         read( 10, *, iostat=stat )
         if ( stat /= 0 ) exit
         numRows = numRows + 1
      end do
      allocate( readCSVFile%row(numRows) )

      ! Rewind and read individual rows
      rewind( 10 )
      do i = 1, numRows
         read( 10, "(a)" ) buffer
         lineLength = len_trim( buffer )

         ! Count number of cells (note: may end in a comma, i.e. empty cell)
         numCols = 1
         do j = 1, lineLength
            if ( buffer(j:j) == ',' ) numCols = numCols + 1
         end do
         allocate( readCSVFile%row(i)%column(numCols) )

         ! Take data delimited by commas
         numCols = 1
         start = 1
         do j = 1, len_trim( buffer )
            if ( buffer(j:j) == ',' ) then
               readCSVFile%row(i)%column(numCols)%value = buffer(start:j-1)
               start = j + 1
               numCols = numCols + 1
            end if
         end do
         if ( start <= lineLength ) readCSVFile%row(i)%column(numCols)%value = buffer(start:lineLength )

      end do
      close( 10 )

   end function readCSVFile

end module MyModule

!===============================================================================

program test
   use MyModule
   implicit none
   type(Spreadsheet) S
   real, allocatable :: R(:)
   integer i, j
   
   S = readCSVFile( "test.csv" )
   allocate( R(size(S%row)) )

   do i = 1, size( S%row )
      write( *, "( *(a20) )" ) ( S%row(i)%column(j)%value, j = 1, size( S%row(i)%column ) )
      read( S%row(i)%column(3)%value, * ) R(i)
   end do

   ! Just the 3rd column, as real
   write( *, * ) "Third column: ", R

end program test
```

Output:

```
                   0          2013/02/20              24.448
                   1          2013/02/20              24.448
                   2          2013/02/20              24.545
                   3          2013/02/20              24.448
                   4          2013/02/20              24.351
                   5          2013/02/20              24.351
 Third column:    24.4480000       24.4480000       24.5450001       24.4480000       24.3509998       24.3509998
```